# C#/XNA Vs. java/vectors for simple game development

Tags: c#, java

I just wanted opinions of the masses on whether to use C# or java with a simple game. I am going to be attempting to recreate the classic game pong with visuals and sounds. Should I use vectors and java to do so, or would it be better, for both the game and the experience I would gain from finishing the project, to use C# and the XNA framework? From the research I have done so far it sounds like C# is definitely a better bet for game programming but I wanted to make sure here first by asking explicitly: java or C# for a simple game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is platform independent so if you are planning on running your game on non windows platforms it has to be your choice. If however you only need your game to run on windows, the C# alternative seems to be a better choice. After all the XNA framework was developed to develop games. It also opens up more options like developing for the Xbox (Knowledge that might become useful later on). In addition Java is just not what it was a few years back so putting more emphasis on learning C# is in my opinion a better investment of time.

Comment: Thanks man. So far you are just affirming my choice to go with C#. I am going to wait for a few more answers but your input has really helped.